# Can seem to pass a struct inside a struct, any ideas?

Tags: c, struct

Every time i try and initialize  a struct to place in an  array called "meal" that contains a struct and an integer it gives  me the following errors:

..\meal_plan.c:92:5: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]

..\meal_plan.c:92:5: warning: (near initialization for 'fpi1.fs') [-Wmissing-braces]

..\meal_plan.c:92:5: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

..\meal_plan.c:92:5: warning: (near initialization for 'fpi1.fs.name[0]') [enabled by default]

I cant for the  life of me figure out whats going wrong. I would really appreciate someone opinion  on what i am missing.

```
  struct food_stuff
  {
      char name [30];
      int foodtype;
      int calories;
      int price;
  };

  typedef struct food_stuff food_stuff;

  struct food_plan_item
   {
      food_stuff fs;
      int qty;
  };

  typedef struct food_plan_item food_plan_item;
```

food_plan_item meal [50];

```
  void choose_food_item()
  {
      puts("Please select one of the available foods:");
      puts("-----------------------------------------");


      for(int i =  0;i <f_cnt;i++)
      {
          printf("\t(%d.) %s\n",i, (foodArray+i)->name);
      }
      puts("-----------------------------------------");
      fflush(stdout);

      char itemSelection [3];
      int chosenitem;

      gets(itemSelection);

      sscanf(itemSelection,"%d",&chosenitem);

      food_stuff *pfs;
      pfs = (foodArray+chosenitem);

      food_plan_item fpi1 = {pfs,1}; **(LINE 92)**

      add_food_plan_item(&fpi1);


  }

  void add_food_plan_item(food_plan_item *p_fpi)
  {

      meal[fpi_count] = *p_fpi;


      fpi_count++;
  }
```

Comment: ok, which line is `.\meal_plan.c:92`?

Comment: food_plan_item fpi1 = {pfs,1};

Comment: pfs is a pointer.  You are trying to initialize the `food_stuff fs` member of `food_plan_item fpi1` to a pointer.

Comment: I have also tried the following                                   food_plan_item fpi1 = {&pfs,1}; I got the same error

Comment: &pfs is the address of the pointer pfs, which doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to copy from what `pfs` points to, to `fpi1.fs`;

```
food_plan_item fpi1 = {.qty = 1}; // designated initializer

memcpy(&fpi1.fs, pfs, sizeof(food_stuff));
```

Or you could declare the `fs` member of `food_plan_item` as a pointer, and then assign pointers directly:

```
food_stuff *fs;
```

Comment: Wow, i would have never gotten  that. Havn't even heard of  that function before. Thank you so much man! You are a legend

Comment: @user2209521 - [memcpy()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) is part of the [tag:c] standard library [tag:stdlib].  Familiarize yourself with it before you write even ome more line of [tag:c] ;-)